# Cycle2 for Wordpress, destroying cycle on mobile, reinitialising on larger than mobile

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, responsive-design, jquery-cycle

I created a slideshow in Wordpress using cycle2 – works ok. I wish do destroy and reinitialise cycle2 on window resize i.e. unwrap the slideshow for mobile devices and rewrap for desktops. I borrowed the following script from user dotty:

```
var contentslideShowElement = $('.content-slide-show');
        var contentSlideShowInitialized = true;
        contentslideShowElement.on( 'cycle-initialised', function() {
            contentSlideShowInitialized = true;
        });
        contentslideShowElement.on( 'cycle-destroyed', function() {
            contentSlideShowInitialized = false;
        });

        $(window).resize(function(){
            destroyContentSlideShowForMobile();
        });

        function destroyContentSlideShowForMobile(){
            if( contentSlideShowInitialized && $(window).width() < 768 ){
                contentslideShowElement.cycle('destroy');
            }

           if( !contentSlideShowInitialized && $(window).width() > 768 ){
                contentslideShowElement.cycle({
                slides: 'li',
                next: '.attachment-large',
                previous: ".prev"
            });
            }
        }
```

Css as follows:

```
<ul class="content-slide-show cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-slides="li">
```

This looks like it should work, unfortunately I'm getting a "contentSlideShowInitialized is not defined".

Any ideas?

Update: at Jorge's suggestion I've set the default for "contentSlideShowInitialized" to true. This makes the wrap/unwrap partly work. Slideshow gets destroyed when I reduce browser width below 700 but if I load the page at a small size the slideshow is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out: no need to watch for "cycle-initialised" and "cycle-destroyed". The following code does the job.

```
var contentslideShowElement = $('.content-slide-show');

        $(window).load(function(){
            decideContentSlideShowForMobile();
        });

        function decideContentSlideShowForMobile(){
            if( $(window).width() < 768 ){
                contentslideShowElement.cycle('destroy');
            }

           if( $(window).width() > 768 ){
                contentslideShowElement.cycle({
                slides: 'li',
                next: '.attachment-large',
                previous: ".prev"
            });
            }
        }   

        $(window).resize(function(){
            destroyContentSlideShowForMobile();
        });

        function destroyContentSlideShowForMobile(){
            if( $(window).width() < 768 ){
                contentslideShowElement.cycle('destroy');
            }

           if( $(window).width() > 768 ){
                contentslideShowElement.cycle({
                slides: 'li',
                next: '.attachment-large',
                previous: ".prev"
            });
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set a default for your `contentSlideShowInitialized` variable:

```
    var contentslideShowElement = $('.content-slide-show');
    var contentSlideShowInitialized = false; // Set default
    contentslideShowElement.on( 'cycle-initialised', function() {
        contentSlideShowInitialized = true;
    });
    contentslideShowElement.on( 'cycle-destroyed', function() {
        contentSlideShowInitialized = false;
    });

    $(window).resize(function(){
        destroyContentSlideShowForMobile();
    });

    function destroyContentSlideShowForMobile(){
        if( contentSlideShowInitialized && $(window).width() < 768 ){
            contentslideShowElement.cycle('destroy');
        }

       if( !contentSlideShowInitialized && $(window).width() > 768 ){
            contentslideShowElement.cycle({
                slides: 'li',
                next: '.attachment-large',
                previous: ".prev"
            });
        }
    }
```